# Setting analyzer per field in query_string

Tags: search, elasticsearch, analyzer

In ES there is possibility of setting analyzer during query. Query I use is like:

```
simple_query_string: {
  query: "THIS_IS_A_SYMBOL and_that_is_the_keyword",
  analyzer: "my_analyzer_including_synonyms",
  fields: ["symbols^2", "keywords"],
  default_operator: "and"
}
```

The problem is that, the search query is analyzed by given analyzer while searching in fields 'symbols' and 'keywords' but 'my_analyzer_including_synonyms' should be applied only to 'keywords' field. I know there is a way to do that by defining search_analyzer during mapping but there is need to change that specified analyzer during search time.

Is there any way to set search analyzer ONLY for 'keywords' field during search time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wha not using two `simple_query_string`, i.e. one per field, and each having a specific analyzer?

Comment: I would like to use query operators like '|', '~' working on multiple fields at once - I think that if I use one `simple_query_string` per field, rules would be applied separatly and result will be not fitting my needs.

Comment: You could try with `bool/must/must_not/should` and see if it works for you

Comment: I used it like:
`bool: {must: [ { bool: { should: [
       {
            simple_query_string: {
              query: "THIS_IS_A_SYMBOL and_that_is_the_keyword",
              fields: ["symbols^2"],
              default_operator: "and"
         }
       },
       {
            simple_query_string: {
              query: "THIS_IS_A_SYMBOL and_that_is_the_keyword",
              analyzer: "my_analyzer_including_synonyms",
              fields: ["keywords"],
              default_operator: "and"
          }
       }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}` and it works wrong

Comment: Well, as far as I know, it is not possible to specify two analyzers at search time. The best you can do is to also split the input string and use the appropriate part in each sub query, i.e `THIS_IS_A_SYMBOL` in the query on `"symbols^2"` and `and_that_is_the_keyword` in the query on `"keywords"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help but I can't use your solution because I don't have information at search time which token could be a symbol or keyword.
I still hope there is a soultion for my problem. Greetings.

Comment: So to sum up, the user inputs this string `THIS_IS_A_SYMBOL and_that_is_the_keyword` (which you can't split because it's completely free text) and you need to match the `"symbols^2"` and `"keywords"` fields but each with their own specific analyzer. is that correct?

Comment: That's right - I know I can achieve this by copying `keywords` field as ie `keywords_en`, `keywords_fr`, set them proper analyzers and dynamically change fields on search time, but this solution seem to be dirty as I need to keep same data in multiple fields only for this purpose.